# variable s tate is not defined but it is

Tags: reactjs

Im starting with React and  following the net Ninja React tutorial and it's not working for me [Complete React Tutorial (& Redux) #14 - Outputting Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At7yOlWkqRQ)

I keep getting the same error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js
>
> Line 6:  'State' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

I have the same code as him

```
import React from 'react';
import Footer from './footer';


function App() {
  state = {
    employes : [
      {nom:'Mehdi',age:20,id:1},
      {nom:'Khalil',age:22,id:2},
      {nom:'Wael',age:26,id:3}
    ]
  }
 
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          <h1>This is my first react app :)</h1>
        </p>

        <Footer employes={this.state.employes}/>
       
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: `state` instead of `State`

Comment: not working I tryed it

Comment: That's just not how you do state in functional components. `const state = { ... }` would work with `{state.employees}`, but you probably want to [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: I overlooked that it is a function component, you need to use `useState` or class based component.

Comment: thank you so much @jonsharpe your answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve your problem. You need to define `state`,

```
const state = {
    employes : [
      {nom:'Mehdi',age:20,id:1},
      {nom:'Khalil',age:22,id:2},
      {nom:'Wael',age:26,id:3}
    ]
}
```

As you are using functional component, you don't have access to `this`, you can use your data as,

```
<Footer employes={state.employes}/>
```

Another way is using [`Hook`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). For functional component, you have `useState` hook. `useState` hook return a pair of `getter`/`setter`.

```
const [employes, setEmployes] = useState([
      {nom:'Mehdi',age:20,id:1},
      {nom:'Khalil',age:22,id:2},
      {nom:'Wael',age:26,id:3}
  ]);
```

Usage,

```
<Footer employes={employes}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the state with an uppercased `S` and you are defining a function component (which doesn't have `this.state`).

Make it lowercase like so and change it to a class component or use the `useState` hook:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    employes : [
      {nom:'Mehdi',age:20,id:1},
      {nom:'Khalil',age:22,id:2},
      {nom:'Wael',age:26,id:3}
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            <h1>This is my first react app :)</h1>
          </p>

          <Footer employes={this.state.employes}/>

        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With the `useState` hook:

```
const App = function() {
  const [employes, setEmployes] = useState([
      {nom:'Mehdi',age:20,id:1},
      {nom:'Khalil',age:22,id:2},
      {nom:'Wael',age:26,id:3}
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          <h1>This is my first react app :)</h1>
        </p>
        <Footer employes={employes}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```